# How to get the column value based on the substitution string in APEX Interactive grid query?

Tags: oracle-apex

I have to pass the dynamic hidden item value in some columns in APEX Interactive grid.

to_char(&P1_ITEM)

P1_ITEM -> YR_2020 (YR_2020 is column name in the table, column value = 1000)

If I pass the :P1_ITEM in the query, I am getting the item string in the report. How to get the column value(1000) instead of the item string(YR_2020)?

CASE WHEN P1_ITEM = 'YR_2021' then YR_2021

else &P1_ITEM

My else part is returning the item string.

Thanks

Comment: please note that your substitution string missing a dot

correct form is `&P1_ITEM.` (with the dot)

Comment: Even if I put dot(&P1_ITEM. ), it is giving the error. Not able to pass the substitution item in the interactive grid.                                                                                      ORA-20999: Parsing returned query results in "ORA-20999: Failed to parse SQL query! <p>ORA-06550: line 7, column 49: ORA-00938: not enough arguments for function</p>".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is expected. It's not possible to use bind variables in pl/sql to define your column names. The bind variable is interpreted as the value it has and not a column name.

For the example below, with source

```
SELECT :P45_SELECTED_COL FROM emp
```

the executed select will be:

```
SELECT 'ENAME' FROM emp;
```

instead of what you want:

```
SELECT ENAME FROM emp;
```

A workaround in apex is to use the type "Function Body returning SQL Query" and dynamically generated the query before running it.
Below is an example for the emp/dept sample dataset.

Note that the apex engine needs to be able to parse the query at compilation time or it will error out so you'll have to provide default values (hence the `NVL` on line 2).

Here is an example of a query on the emp table where the first column is determined through a page item.

```
DECLARE
  l_selected_col VARCHAR2(100) := NVL(:P45_SELECTED_COL,'ENAME');
  l_statement VARCHAR2(4000):= 
  q'!
select ##SELECTED_COL## AS COL1,
       JOB,
       MGR,
       HIREDATE,
       SAL,
       COMM,
       DEPTNO
  from EMP!';
BEGIN
  RETURN REPLACE(l_statement,'##SELECTED_COL##',l_selected_col);
END;
```

To adjust the column header in the report to the selected column, set the column heading attribute to  `&P45_SELECTED_COL.`

Comment: Is P45_ENAME a column name in the Interactive grid? Is this the classic report or Interactive grid query? For my case, P1_ITEM is a column name in the Interactive grid.

Comment: Updated my answer, but I'm not sure I answered your question because I don't quite understand it. If you're trying to set the column heading, where are you getting that sql error ? Can you explain in more detail what it is you're trying to achieve, maybe with some screenshots and a sample query on the emp/dept schema like I did ?

Comment: So in the OCT column, i want the value 1000 to be displayed, but it is displaying the column name (SEP) in the report, instead of the 1000(value of the SEP column)

Comment: @user10777723 please don't put this information in the comments. Instead edit your question with the additional information and properly format your code. How am I supposed to understand this dump of plain text. Also please try to create a minimal reproducible example (all irrelevant stuff removed) so other users can try this.

Comment: Re-wrote my answer

Comment: Hi Koes Lostrie, thank you so much for the substitution string solution. I have one more question in the dynamic pivot columns. I have edited in my question. Can you please provide the solution if possible?

Comment: I'd file another question for that - this is a different issue, unrelated to getting the column base on page item. Also, now these comments are only between you and me, no one else sees the updates (unless they drill down) so you're missing the knowledge of the community. If you do ask another question, consider creating a proper reproducible case. I don't have access to your data structure and database so I can't try out things. Also, please don't update the question with the actual solution - that makes the question unusable for others...

Comment: Ok, I have removed my second query from this question. Thanks for all your help.